# matlab command obtain best fit of form $y(t)=a_1+a_2*t+a_3*sin(t) $

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Is there a matlab command obtain best fit of form y(t)=a_1+a_2*t+a_3*sin(t) ???

Cannot find a command because of the sine function

***thank you!!***

Comment: [This Matlab app](https://es.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/interactive-curve-and-surface-fitting-.html) may help. If I remember correctly you can fit arbitrary functions. Or maybe [see this example](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/programmatic-fitting.html#f1-7306) to do it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could use *fittype* command.

Here is the code might help:

```
%sample data
x=[1;2;3;4;5];y=3+4*x+5*sin(x)+rand(5,1)*0.01;

%curve-fitting
p=fittype('a_1+a_2*t+a_3*sin(t)','independent','t')  
f=fit(x,y,p)  

%plot
plot(f,x,y);
```

It will return f like this: (there could be little different because of random data, but the answer is correct [3,4,5])

f =

```
 General model:
 f(t) = a_1+a_2*t+a_3*sin(t)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a_1 =       2.996  (2.95, 3.043)
   a_2 =       4.002  (3.987, 4.017)
   a_3 =       5.005  (4.978, 5.032)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fh = @(a,t) a(1) + a(2) * t + a(3) * sin(t);
a = [2 -1 3];
x = ...;
y = ...;

fit = lsqcurvefit(fh,a,x,y);

figure();
plot(x,y,'ko',x,fh(a,x),'b-');
title('Result');
legend('Data','Fitted');
```

Reference to official documentation with examples:

https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html